# synchronising JSON useEffect

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a local json file (`data.json`) and I want to pull data into my React App. Console logs work fine, but the data is not available in the React state to work with.

I've been following [this blog](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetch-data-from-a-json-file-in-a-react-app). Accordingly, I have `data.json` under the `public` folder of the project.

Here is the code:

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("data.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("response", response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (myJson) {
        console.log("myjson", myJson);
        setData(myJson);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    console.log("data is", data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data && data.length > 0 && data.map((item) => <p>{item.text}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Console.log outputs the following:

```
data is []
data is []
response Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/data.json', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/data.json', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
myjson {1: {…}, 2: {…}}
  1: {text: 'first item', done: true}
  2: {text: 'second item', done: false}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
myjson {1: {…}, 2: {…}}
  1: {text: 'first item', done: true}
  2: {text: 'second item', done: false}
  [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I have read several questions / answers on stackoverflow, and I understand that the data is asynchronous but I don't get how to call it only when it's ready.
I've tried separate useEffect calls, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the return, that's not working in your code:

You receive an object in your console.log here:

```
myjson {1: {…}, 2: {…}}
  1: {text: 'first item', done: true}
  2: {text: 'second item', done: false}
```

but you try to test on `data.` in the return, which will always yield `undefined`.

You could test on the `Object.values` and use those for your mapping to get the desired result:

```
return (
    <div>
      {data && Object.values(data).length > 0 && Object.values(data).map((item) => <p>{item.text}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: yes that was the problem. -thanks!